# Canot enter TWRP recovery because of "fastboot erase userdata"

Tags: partitions, bootloader, rom

I want to flash a new ROM for my Android phone.

I clean data by `fastboot erase userdata`

but after that, I can not enter TWRP recovery because can not mount /data

I tried `fastboot format userdata`

then below errors occured:

```
Couldn't parse erase-block-size '0x'.
Couldn't parse logical-block-size '0x'.
```

So how to make the TWRP work again?

Or how to rebuild the `data` partition by `fastboot`?

Comment: Try adding the the format to the fastboot command. Like: `fastboot format:ext4 userdata`

Comment: @BoLawson Thank you very much, but I have not opportunity to verify it again. I flashed newest version TWRP,  this TWRP can be entered, and I format `data` partition in this TWRP. Then everything was OK.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but from a different reason. I was trying to unlock the bootloader, and I think my phone erased all the existent data for protection.

After I installed TWRP custom recovery, then my phone started booting, showing those errors every time TWRP appeared and restarting it again.

In my case, I solved the problem **selecting recovery mode**, then formatting the partitions from TWRP wipe screen. I took me a while to realise that my phone was displaying TWRP, but the phone wasn't in recovery at that point.